# Написал код(часть скопировал с форума), работает! но как я не понимаю Почему 2 символа \\?и что происходит в цикле While?

Tags: java

```
package chapterfirst;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SumNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите цифры через запятую и нажмите <Enter>");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sequenseRandom = keyboard.next();
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sequenseRandom);
            int start = 0;
            int result;
            int sum =0;
            while (matcher.find(start)) {
               String value = sequenseRandom.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
               result = Integer.parseInt(value);
               start = matcher.end();
               sum += result;  
            }
            System.out.print(sum); 
            keyboard.close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Два слеша, чтобы один заэкранировал другой.и у вас получился паттерн `\d+`.

Comment: А Заэкранировал это как?

Comment: @Vartlok, может ответ напишешь? :)

Comment: @Grundy я очень ленивый, но если вы просите)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Есть разные спец символы(табуляция, двойные кавычки, перенос строки и т.д.) и чтобы их можно было можно было использовать в строках используется слешь(`\`) и вот чтобы это был слешь именно в строке, а не как символ экранирования, надо его тоже заэкранировать. Полный список всех таки символов можно посмотреть [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

А т.к. вам нужна регулярка `\d+`, то надо использовать двойной слешь(`\\`).

Цикл `while` выполняется, пока во введенной строке еще остаются необработанные числа. Каждое нашедшее число парситься в Integer и складывается с уже ищеющимся результатом. Подробнее про Pattern [читаем тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html), про Matcher [читаем тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html).

Comment: ну и про цикл while надо было рассказать, что выдираются числа из строки и складываются :-)